# Why can't a radio button stay selected when typing in text input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

In a project, I need a form to include radio buttons and have the last item be an input field. We are using AngularJS.

Binding vm.appModel.amount to the input field and the different radio button selections will work: the data used upon clicking on the submit button will be valid.

However, if the user clicks in the text input and starts typing, the radio button loses it's checked value, even if many checks are in place on the text input to keep the checked value set to true. ([See code](https://github.com/jansensan/test-angularjs-text-input-in-radio-group/blob/master/www/templates/radio-form-tmpl.html#L41))

```
ng-focus="isManualInputSelected = true;"
ng-change="isManualInputSelected = true;"
ng-click="isManualInputSelected = true;"
```

On the radio input, this should keep it as activated, however doesn't. ([See code](https://github.com/jansensan/test-angularjs-text-input-in-radio-group/blob/master/www/templates/radio-form-tmpl.html#L34))

```
ng-checked="isManualInputSelected"
```

See the repo: https://github.com/jansensan/test-angularjs-text-input-in-radio-group

Any guidance on how to make sure to keep the radio button checked while typing in the text field would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a pull request for you that fixes the problem.

https://github.com/jansensan/test-angularjs-text-input-in-radio-group/pull/1

As jw56578 already said vm.appModel.amount property gets overwritten by adding a value in the input which means the radio button is no longer checked.

I've refactored your code so it includes a payment object with the properties amount and type. For the manual payment payment.type will now be set (and this controls the radio button) and the amount is stored in payment.amount.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification @Daniël and jw56578, the last radio button indeed didn't need to be bound to a property. I went a bit a different way than the PR (the payment.type value was superfluous in my case), but it helped a lot! I'll adapt my repo soon to show the update, and where I took what I learned from that PR.

Answer (score 0):

you have bound ng-model to the vm.appModel.amount property
the value of the radio button is 0
the radio button will only be checked when the value of vm.appModel.amount property is 0
you have bound the text boxes to the same property so when you start typing you change the value to something other than 0, so then the radio button gets unchecked
Seems like there is no point to binding the radio button to the amount property with ng-model. Just remove that.